# SystemUsers/Peer does not have permission='CREATE_ADDRESS'

Tags: corda

I'm setting up a local network using docker image `corda-zulu-5.0-snapshot:latest`, using the node configurations generated by `corda-network-bootstrapper-4.1.jar`, I'm getting the following error when starting a flow with the sample IOU workflow:

```
Connection closed due to error on remote side: `AMQ119032: User: 
SystemUsers/Peer does not have permission='CREATE_ADDRESS' on address
p2p.inbound.DL6fmb1MCWbxHQNwQ9F9YxiSv7Sx3X92y44hMPfDpHbuG3` 
{localLegalName=O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB, remoteLegalName=O=PartyB, L=New York, C=US, serverMode=false}
```

Comment: Did you able to find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you implement the node.conf file?

One of the requirements to get Corda running with docker is mounted node.conf at location `/etc/corda/node.config`

Here is the link: https://docs.corda.net/docker-image.html

Comment: I do have that properly mounted: `-v /path/to/folder/containing/node.conf:/etc/corda`